# Convert Cross join of sql To Linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

i have a table

```
SELECT JM.jobNum+'.'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,TL.tlPhasenum) AS [COST CODE],EM.empnum+'&#8204;' AS [EMPLOYEE NUMBER],TL.tlDateWorked AS [DATE],tl.tlOT,tl.tlStraightTime INTO #TempTable
FROM mqTimeReportingTimeLogs AS TL
    INNER JOIN mqJobMaster AS JM ON TL.tlJobId=JM.jobId
    INNER JOIN mqEmployeeMaster AS EM ON TL.tlEmployeeId=EM.empId
    WHERE 
    TL.tlCompanyId in (select * from #TempCompanies) 
    AND (@weekending='' or tlWeekEnding=CONVERT(DATE,@weekending)) 
    AND (@jobid=0 or TL.tlJobId=@jobid)
    AND (@startdate='' or TL.tldateworked between convert(date,@startdate) and convert(date,@enddate))
```

and the following query to split on row to two

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable2
 FROM (
    SELECT [COST CODE],[EMPLOYEE NUMBER],[DATE],value as [Hours],col as [Time Type]
    from #TempTable
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        VALUES('1',tlStraightTime),('2',tlOT) --1:ST  2:OT
    ) C (COL, VALUE)
 ) SRC
```

Now i want to implement the same thing in linq ,How to use this logic in LINQ

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you translate the first query. Then a `CROSS APPLY` can be done as a `from`...`from`...`select`.

Comment: However, I don't think you will be able to run the second query server side, you'll have to pull over the first query and then use LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have translated the `TempTable` query into LINQ, something like:

```
var TempTable = from tl in mqTimeReportingTimeLogs ...
```

then you can do the second query by creating an inline table with `Select` and `Concat` (e.g. `SELECT` and `UNION ALL`) which LINQ to SQL can translate:

```
var ans = from t in TempTable
          from c in TempTable.Take(1).Select(_ => new { col = 1, value = t.tlStraightTime }).Concat(TempTable.Take(1).Select(_ => new { col = 2, value = t.tlOT }))
          select new {
              t.CostCode,
              t.EmployeeNumber,
              t.Date,
              c.col,
              c.value
          };
```